# Summation of different rows and different columns by SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

In the following table I am going to calculate column S:

```
 Week     L       C1      C2      C3      C4      C5      C6      S
   1    L1=3      258     141     140      21      51     197    S1=1000
   2       7      291     261      64     275      72     249
   3       1      287     164      99     222     149     172
   4       3      163     193    A=200     95     170      51
   5       4      193      11     271    B=300    199      26
   6    L6=2      213     120      53     210    C=400     43    S6=507 
   7       5       36     208     243     163     126    D=100
   8       3      174      56     282     274     214      222
   9       1       63     295    M=222    153     136      173
   10      4      191     114     195     N=8      28      188
   11      3      125     293      38      56    O=277     11
```

As a general formula I want to find column S based on the below equations:

If L >= 3, S = C3 in three weeks later + C4 in four weeks later + C5 in five weeks later + C6 in six weeks later. For example S1 = A + B + c + D = 1000

If  L < 3, S = C3 in three weeks later + C4 in four weeks later + C5 in five weeks later. For example S6= M + N + O = 507.

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Okay, so where is your problem exactly? What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I am going to calculate column S! My current calculations refer only each row's summation. I could not figure out how to change rows and column for summation function that I need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first got in my mind:

```
SELECT c1.*, 
        CASE WHEN c1.L >=3 THEN ISNULL(c2.C3,0) + ISNULL(c3.C4,0) + ISNULL(c4.C5,0) + ISNULL(c5.C6,0)
        ELSE ISNULL(c2.C3,0) +ISNULL(c3.C4,0) + ISNULL(c4.C5,0) END as S
FROM YourTableName c1
LEFT JOIN YourTableName c2 
    ON c1.[Week] + 3 = c2.[week]
LEFT JOIN YourTableName c3
    ON c2.[Week] + 1 = c3.[week]
LEFT JOIN YourTableName c4
    ON c3.[Week] + 1 = c4.[week]
LEFT JOIN YourTableName c5
    ON c4.[Week] + 1 = c5.[week]
```

Output:

```
Week    L   C1  C2  C3  C4  C5  C6  S
1       3   258 141 140 21  51  197 1000
2       7   291 261 64  275 72  249 829
3       1   287 164 99  222 149 172 430
4       3   163 193 200 95  170 51  841
5       4   193 11  271 300 199 26  474
6       2   213 120 53  210 400 43  507
7       5   36  208 243 163 126 100 251
8       3   174 56  282 274 214 222 38
9       1   63  295 222 153 136 173 0
10      4   191 114 195 8   28  188 0
11      3   125 293 38  56  277 11  0
```

**EDIT:**

For SQL Server 2012 an onward you can use [LEAD](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213125.aspx)

```
SELECT  *,
        CASE WHEN L >= 3 THEN 
            LEAD(C3, 3, 0) OVER (ORDER BY [Week]) +
            LEAD(C4, 4, 0) OVER (ORDER BY [Week]) +
            LEAD(C5, 5, 0) OVER (ORDER BY [Week]) +
            LEAD(C6, 6, 0) OVER (ORDER BY [Week]) 
        ELSE 
            LEAD(C3, 3, 0) OVER (ORDER BY [Week]) +
            LEAD(C4, 4, 0) OVER (ORDER BY [Week]) +
            LEAD(C5, 5, 0) OVER (ORDER BY [Week])
        END as S
FROM YourTableName
```

Output will be the same.

Comment: Yes, that's the first solution I thought of, too. Another would be subqueries in the `SELECT` clause, and yet another `LEAD` in case the weeks have no gaps. Given that we don't see any SQL and no hint to a possible solution in the request, I am afraid the OP didn't even start to think about how to write the query, but simply wanted us to do the work instead.